# Add custom view in UICollectionView

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I tried lot but not find any way to add custom view in `UICollectionView` before starting on each `UICollectionViewCell`. I have attached screenshot, what i want.

I have used UICollectionView to display object section vise and indicate arrow which view custom view i want to add.

Help appreciate..
Thanks in Advance.

[image].

Answer (score 2):

You will have to write your own UICollectionViewLayout and give it a decoration view (or possibly, if this view is tied to the layout of the section data, some new kind of supplementary view).